# Algorithm to enlarge/scale/inflate/enbiggen a triangle

Tags: geometry, transform

I'm looking for an algorithm to make a triangle larger by a given scaling factor.  If I multiply the 3 coordinates by the scaling factor, and the triangle is not centred on the origin, then the triangle will also translate as well as scale which is not the required effect.

The triangle needs to grow while remaining in the same place.

My initial thought would be to find the triangle centre, offset the triangle to the origin, scale, offset back again.  However there's presumably a more efficient way than this?

Also, if this is the only way to do it, what's the most appropriate way of finding the centre of the triangle?

Comment: a) First worry about correctness, and then *if* you find you're too slow, worry about efficiency; b) There are [at least 3761 ways to define the 'centre' of a triangle](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) - only you can decide which one you want to use :)

Comment: The standard wisdom doesn't apply in this case :) It's actually for a rough-and-ready 3D rendering that must deal with thousands of animated triangles, and I'm more worried about efficiency than correctness. Also, I need advice on choosing the correct centre, if the algorithm depends on it.

Comment: This is possible only for [cromulent](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cromulent) triangles.

Comment: More efficient than 4 additions and 2 multiplications (Ok, plus 4 additions and 2 multiplications for center computation)? I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

The center of the triangle should be at

> (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3, (y1 + y2 + y3) / 3

Answer (score 1):

using this algorithm to generate new coordinates will work well

```
X_new = X_cg + (X_old-X_cg)*Scale
Y_new = Y_cg + (Y_old-Y_cg)*Scale
```

`X_cg` is the geometric center of your geometry

Comment: In fact this is exactly his current approach. But well, you're right in that it's also the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the center point, you can do this:

1. Calculate the distance from one of the points of the triangle to the center, in a vector. Ie. (3,4).
2. Double those values (or triple, whatever you want). Ie. (6,8)
3. Plot the new point in comparison to the center. Ie. if the center was (1,2), you would add the new point to that and get (7,10)
4. Repeat for the other points of the triangle

This should work :)

To work out the center, I would work out the difference from the highest point to the lowest, halve that, and add it to the lowest (so you have the middle of those two), and then repeat for left and right. That should give you the center.